# Using a .dll in Unity C#

Tags: ios, .net, dll, unity-game-engine, compatibility

I am currently working with Unity3D, and need to import a .dll file compiled in VS2008, using .net 2.0. It works perfectly well on the PC version and it works just like I want it to, but it somehow breaks my iOS build. I'm not even using the .dll on mobile devices, and the code linking to the dll (DllImport) is compiled only in the PC build.

I'm getting the following error when building for iOS :

```
ArgumentException: The Assembly Microsoft.VisualC is referenced by mydll. But the dll is not allowed to be included or could not be found.
```

I've changed to api compatibility level (in the player settings for all platforms in unity) to .net 2.0, and built my dll targetting the 2.0 .net level as well.

Why is the dll even in my build ? What are the correct steps to import a .dll, maybe I've missed something crucial ?

QUICK EDIT : The .net api compatibility wasn't set correctly in the end for iphone, but I'm still getting some error :

```
Error building Player: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I think it's during the AOT cross compile phase of the player creation. Maybe someone knows how to deal with this ?

Also, maybe it was unclear in my question, but my DLL uses managed code to be able to access .net functions.

UPDATE : Been working on this a bit on my end, now I'm wondering if there is a way to simply exclude this .dll from my iOS build ? (apart from doing it manually everytime I want to build). I can't seem to find out a way to do this. I've tried stripping, but it doesn't work well with other parts of my application (breaks some things), and now I'm a bit lost. I can manually remove and add it as a workaround but would really like a cleaner solution !

Comment: I wouldn't expect a DLL built in Visual Studio to be usable in an iOS application.

Comment: Exactly, and I am not using it in my iOS app. It's for the PC version of the app, but for some reason it is included in, and prevents me from building, my iOS app.

Comment: How would we know what's causing that?  The usual troubleshooting applies; check your iOS code for bogus references to the DLL, check your IDE's configuration and reference files.

Comment: Checked my code, everything seens to be in order.

Comment: If you remove the dll from your project, does iOS build properly?

Comment: Yes. I believe the problem is because I am using managed code (System::String, for example) in my Dll. iOS can't cross-compile that, so it prevents me from building. Thing is, I don't need the dll for my iOS build, only the Windows standalone one.

Comment: @ChanibaL see my last comment and question update

Comment: @Bypp: maybe my answer will help?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you cannot strip a dll from only one platform.

What you can do is you could load the dll yourself when needed. Change the dll extention to `.bytes`, load it as `byte[]` and push to `System.Reflection.Assembly.Load`.

This **should** work, but it may have some side effects.

Comment: What kind of side effects would this approach have ? For now, I'd rather do it manually then it breaking apart later...

Comment: Not exactly sure. My guess is statics might have problems with initiation, AOT could break totally or just generics (in webplayer). Maybe something monobehaviour related wont fire. If you test it properly you should be safe.

Comment: Dynamic code has a chance to get rejected by App Store: https://answers.unity.com/questions/892645/assemblyload-on-ios.html

Comment: With the switch to IL2CPP (required with iOS 11), this probably won't work at all on iOS (or WebGL).